# Press and Hold gesture in windows

Tags: c++, winapi

[Windows Touch Gesture Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940543(v=vs.85).aspx)  mentions Press and Hold Gesture but there is nothing such as GID_PRESSANDHOLD identifier. I cannot use WM_TOUCH message as it will disable WM_GESTURE message which is a necessity for me.
Has anyone implemented Press and hold gesture on windows, Is it possible to implement it without WM_TOUCH message?